# Winsock / BSD Sockets - Accept TCP connections with destination IP different from local IP

Tags: sockets, proxy

I am forwarding some outgoing TCP traffic on LAN (eventually UDP as well) to a local (transparent) proxy server before sending them out on the internet. The packets are forwared correctly it seems, I can see the SYN's in Wireshark.

The problem is that accept() bound to a port X doesn't accept a connection with destination port X and a destination IP different from the proxy server's own IP it seems, which was something I expected.

Is there a way around this in Winsock or in Linux sockets? How can I achieve the accept() or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux sockets have the option `IP_TRANSPARENT`. See the linux man page ip:

> IP_TRANSPARENT (since Linux 2.6.24)
>
> Setting this boolean option enables transparent proxying on
>   this socket.  This socket option allows the calling
>   application to bind to a nonlocal IP address and operate both
>   as a client and a server with the foreign address as the local
>   endpoint.  ...

As far as I know the option is not available for windows sockets.